# Check if a list is a rotation of another list that works with duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have this function for determining if a list is a rotation of another list:

```
def isRotation(a,b):
  if len(a) != len(b):
    return False

  c=b*2
  i=0

  while a[0] != c[i]:
    i+=1

  for x in a:
    if x!= c[i]:
      return False
    i+=1

  return True
```

e.g.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [2,3,1]
>>> isRotation(a, b)
True
```

How do I make this work with duplicates? e.g.

```
a = [3,1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,3,1,2]
```

And can it be done in `O(n)`time?

Comment: Does the amount of duplicates matter? Example - [1,2,3] and [3,1,2,3] are they different?

Comment: Yes, those are definitely different.

Comment: Well, in that case, keep a count of the lengths and reject a match if they are different.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: add a `if len(a) != len(b): return False` (or equivalent) statement

Comment: It is already there. I mean, if two arrays had different lengths they can no way be a rotation of one another.

Comment: What do you mean by rotation? A permutation? To me it sounds more like pattern matching.

Comment: Don't you mean shuffle, instead of rotation? (That is: you want to know if you can shuffle the members of one array, so that array will be equal to an other array).

Comment: @MTilsted Rotating an array is taking N elements from one end and putting them at the other, it's not a shuffle where any order works:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]

Comment: Highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553522/interview-question-check-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-other-string There are many more where that came from...

Comment: I know. Which is why I asked if he wanted a shuffle or rotate. For a rotate the solution is just: Find the lowest value in both arrays:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it in `0(n)` time and `0(1)` space using a modified version of a maximal suffixes algorithm:

From [Jewels of Stringology](https://books.google.ie/books?id=9NdohJXtIyYC&lpg=PA139&ots=ln6d-CM3Gb&dq=Equivalence%20of%20cyclic%20two%20words&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=Equivalence%20of%20cyclic%20two%20words&f=false):
**Cyclic equality of words**

> A rotation of a word u of length n is any word of the form u[k + 1...n][l...k]. Let u, w be two words of the same length n. They are said to be cyclic-equivalent if u(i) == w(j) for some i, j.
>
> If words u and w are written as circles, they are cyclic-equivalent if the circles coincide after appropriate rotations.
>
> There are several linear-time algorithms for testing the cyclic-equivalence
>   of two words. The simplest one is to apply any string matching algorithm to pattern pat = u and text = ww because words u and w are cyclic=equivalent if pat occurs in text.
>
> Another algorithm is to find maximal suffixes of uu and ww and check if
>   they are identical on prefixes of size n. We have chosen this problem because there is simpler interesting algorithm, working in linear time and constant space simultaneously, which deserves presentation.

```
Algorithm Cyclic-Equivalence(u, w)
{ checks cyclic equality of u and w of common length n }
    x := uu; y := ww;
    i := 0; j := 0;
    while (i < n) and (j < n) do begin
        k := 1;
        while x[i + k] = y[j + k] do k := k + 1;
        if k > n then return true;
        if x[i + k]> y[i + k] then i := i + k else j := j + k;
        { invariant }
    end;
    return false;
```

Which translated to python becomes:

```
def cyclic_equiv(u, v):
    n, i, j = len(u), 0, 0
    if n != len(v):
        return False
    while i < n and j < n:
        k = 1
        while k <= n and u[(i + k) % n] == v[(j + k) % n]:
            k += 1
        if k > n:
            return True
        if u[(i + k) % n] > v[(j + k) % n]:
            i += k
        else:
            j += k
    return False
```

Running a few examples:

```
In [4]: a = [3,1,2,3,4]   
In [5]: b =[3,4,3,1,2]   
In [6]: cyclic_equiv(a,b)
Out[6]: True    
In [7]: b =[3,4,3,2,1]    
In [8]: cyclic_equiv(a,b)
Out[8]: False    
In [9]: b =[3,4,3,2]    
In [10]: cyclic_equiv(a,b)
Out[10]: False
In [11]: cyclic_equiv([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
Out[11]: True
In [12]: cyclic_equiv([3,1,2],[1,2,3])
Out[12]: True
```

A more naive approach would be to use a collections.deque to rotate the elements:

```
def rot(l1,l2):
    from collections import deque
    if l1 == l2:
        return True
    # if length is different we cannot get a match
    if len(l2) != len(l1):
        return False
    # if any elements are different we cannot get a match
    if set(l1).difference(l2):
        return False
    l2,l1 = deque(l2),deque(l1)
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        l2.rotate() # l2.appendleft(d.pop()) 
        if l1 == l2:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: here's [c++ implementation for comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732159/4279).

Answer (score 29):

The following meta-algorithm will solve it.

- Build a concatenation of `a`, e.g., `a =  [3,1,2,3,4]` => `aa =  [3,1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3,4]`.
- Run any string adaptation of a string-matching algorithm, e.g., [Boyer Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) to find `b` in `aa`.

---

One particularly easy implementation, which I would first try, is to use [Rabin Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) as the underlying algorithm. In this, you would

- calculate the [Rabin Fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) for `b`
- calculate the Rabin fingerprint for `aa[: len(b)]`, `aa[1: len(b) + 1]`, ..., and compare the lists only when the fingerprints match

Note that

- The Rabin fingerprint for a sliding window can be calculated iteratively very efficiently (read about it in the Rabin-Karp link)
- If your list is of integers, you actually have a slightly easier time than for strings, as you don't need to think what is the numerical hash value of a letter
  -

Comment: So, you are suggesting that I convert it to strings. That doesn't sound very efficient. Any ideas if a O(n^2) solution would be better compared to turning it into a string?

Comment: I am certainly not suggesting that you convert it into a string, but rather that you should adapt a string matching algorithm for it. Will fill in more details.

Answer (score 8):

I think you could use something like this:

```
a1 = [3,4,5,1,2,4,2]
a2 = [4,5,1,2,4,2,3]

# Array a2 is rotation of array a1 if it's sublist of a1+a1
def is_rotation(a1, a2):
   if len(a1) != len(a2):
       return False

   double_array = a1 + a1

   return check_sublist(double_array, a2)

def check_sublist(a1, a2):
   if len(a1) < len(a2):
       return False

   j = 0
   for i in range(len(a1)):
        if a1[i] == a2[j]:
              j += 1
        else:
              j = 0

        if j == len(a2):
              return True

   return j == len(a2)
```

Just common sense if we are talking about interview questions:

- we should remember that solution should be easy to code and to describe.
- do not try to remember solution on interview. It's better to remember core principle and re-implement it.

Comment: The "in" key doesn't seem to work and implementing that which works for duplicates is my problem.

Comment: @RahatMahbub, yes, you are right, I will fix it. Duplicates are not a problem in this task.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that I convert it to strings. That doesn't sound very efficient. Any ideas if a O(n^2) solution would be better compared to turning it into a string?

Comment: @RahatMahbub, you can try this one :) It's simplest way to check that one list is a sublist of other.

Comment: it should be `len(a1) != len(a2):` a1 could be bigger that a2 therefore also having no chance of matching

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I didn't get you comment. I check that `a2` is sublist of `a1`. It means that `a1` should be equal or bigger.

Comment: The OP is no looking for sublists, they are seeing if rotating the second array will equal the first array

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes, that's why there is a `is_rotation` function :)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to check the length of a1 vs the length of a2 first, if they are not equal then there is not much point doing anything else

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Checking the sublist for twice the array is what I am doing as well, except my implementation doesn't work when there's a duplicate. This one does, I am just testing it for a few more cases.

Comment: @RahatMahbub, try `is_rotation([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1, 1]))`, I presume the correct answer is False as the lists are different lengths so impossible to be the same?

Comment: The second `if len(a1) < len(a2):` is redundant, if the lengths are the same the a1+a1 cannot be smaller

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, they could be used independent.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (I couldn't get the `b in aa` solution to work), you can 'rotate' your list and check if the rotated list is equal to b:

```
def is_rotation(a, b):

    for n in range(len(a)):
        c = c = a[-n:] + a[:-n]
        if b == c:
            return True

    return False
```

I believe this would be O(n) as it only has one `for` loop. Hope it helps

Comment: You forgot that `in` is O(n) itself :)

Comment: This is very cool but due to b==c, the running time will be O(n^2) I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
def func(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    elif a == b:
        return True

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(b) if x == a[0] and i > 0]

    for i in indices:
        if a == b[i:] + b[:i]:
            return True

    return False
```

And this also:

```
def func(a, b):
    length = len(a)

    if length != len(b):
         return False

    i = 0
    while i < length:
        if a[0] == b[i]:
            j = i
            for x in a:
                if x != b[j]:
                    break
                j = (j + 1) % length
            return True
        i += 1

    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can represent these as strings instead, just do:

```
def cyclically_equivalent(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and a in 2 * b
```

Otherwise, one should get a sublist searching algorithm, such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt (Google gives some implementations) and do

```
def cyclically_equivalent(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and sublist_check(a, 2 * b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try testing the performance of just using the rotate() function in the deque collection:

```
from collections import deque

def is_rotation(a, b):

    if len(a) == len(b):
        da = deque(a)
        db = deque(b)

        for offset in range(len(a)):
            if da == db:
                return True

            da.rotate(1)

    return False
```

In terms of performance, do you need to make this calculation many times for small arrays, or for few times on very large arrays? This would determine whether or not special case testing would speed it up.

Comment: It was an interview question so there was no particular requirements to size. But rotating with a for loop should result in O(n^2). My algorithm does do an O(n) for any input except for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is a string search algorithm that runs in O(n) where n is the length of a text S (assuming the existence of preconstructed table T, which runs in O(m) where m is the length of the search string). All in all it is O(n+m).

You could do a similar pattern matching algorithm inspired by KMP.

- Concatenate a list to itself, like `a+a` or `b+b` - this is the searched text/list with 2*n elements
- Build the table T based on the other list (be it `b` or `a`) - this is done in O(n)
- Run the KMP inspired algorithm - this is done in O(2*n) (because you concatenate a list to itself)

> Overall time complexity is O(2*n+n) = O(3*n) which is in O(n)